# How to access global variable from .so in executable

Tags: c++, gcc

Please help me, How to access run time varibale's data(att) in stub.exe of att variable that is defined in proc.so,
I have created proc.so and linked with attol.exe and stub.exe and
attol.exe updates 'att' variable and stub.exe is accessing 'att' variable and prints att's value.

I have used below commands to compile the code :

> g++ -Wall -c attol.cc proc.cc stub.cc 
>   g++ -shared -dynamiclib -fPIC -o libproc.so proc.o -ldl 
>   g++ -rdynamic -o attol.exe attol.o /users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so -ldl 
>   g++ -rdynamic -o stub.exe stub.o /users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so -ldl

When i am running both .exe at different terminal then attol.exe showing 'att:4' value  but stub.exe is showing incorrect value, 
But stub.exe should display '4' value or updated value.

**out put attol.exe:**

> ./attol.exe

Value of att is : 4
Enter the value of att :

**out put stub.exe:**

> ./stub.exe

Att : 0

**----Complete Code Details----**

**proc.h:**

```
  #ifndef __X_H_INCLUDED__  
  #define __X_H_INCLUDED__

  extern int att;
  int fun();
  #endif
```

**proc.cc:**

```
  #include<iostream.h>
  #include "proc.h"
  int att;
  int fun ()
  {
  att=4;
  return 0;
  }
```

Above code is generating proc.o and then this proc.o will converted into proc.so with below commands:

> g++ -Wall -c attol.cc proc.cc stub.cc 
>   g++ -shared -dynamiclib -fPIC -o libproc.so proc.o -ldl

**attol.cc:**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "proc.h"
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int ch=1;
fun();
cout<<"\n Value of att is : "<<att; 
   do{
   cout<<"\n Enter the value of att : ";
   cin>>att;
   cout<<"\n Do you want to continue the : ";
   cin>>ch;
   }while(ch!=0);
return 0;
}
```

attol.cc file creates attol.exe by using below command

> g++ -rdynamic -o attol.exe attol.o /users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so -ldl

**out put:**

> Value of att is : 4
>   Enter the value of att :

**stub.cc:**

```
  #include <iostream.h>
  #include <dlfcn.h>

  int main ()
  {
    void *handle;
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

   int  *att =(int*) dlsym(handle, "att");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    cout<<"\n Att : " <<*att;
    cout<<"\n " ;
    dlclose(handle);
   }
```

stub.cc file creates stub.exe by using below command

> g++ -rdynamic -o stub.exe stub.o /users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so -ldl

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  Your `main()` for `stub.exe` never calls `fun()` from libproc, so there's no reason your `att` variable should have a value at all.  I'm surprised it doesn't result in an error actually.

Comment: 'Main()' is calling 'fun()' and it is printing '4' value when attol.exe executed.

Comment: Why do you use `/users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so` at one place and `./libproc.so` on another. Are you sure, they are the same?

Comment: both are same path, after change the code still( ./libproc.so -> /users/hbharti/DLOPEN/proc/libproc.so). still, i am getting same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the code, there seems to be a fundamental issue with the core-logic.

> A shared-object (`*.so`) is loaded into the executing process's memory address space.

However it is **NOT** shared across multiple processes. When 2 or more executables attempt to access the same shared-object (`*.so`), they both get independent copies of it mapped into their respective memory address spaces.

Data (even globals) within a shared-object (`*so`) are **NOT** shared across 2 or more executables.

Comment: I didn't even realize the OP was expecting the data to be shared between processes.  No wonder it made no sense...